# CSS keyframes are working on Code Loader but not on Fiddle or my page

Tags: css, html, css-animations

I'll start with I am new to keyframes so this is prob a newbie error.

I want to get this code loader code working on my page:
https://codepen.io/gbrent/pen/XPMGXP

It does not work on my page or fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qmL7x9j2/

HTML:

```
<div class="loader">
  <span>{</span><span>}</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .loader {
    color: #0079f2;

    font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30vh;

    opacity: 0.8;

    span {
        display: inline-block;
        animation: pulse 0.4s alternate infinite ease-in-out;

        &:nth-child(odd) {
        animation-delay: 0.4s;
        }
    }
    }

    @keyframes pulse {
        to {
            transform: scale(0.8);
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Am I missing something here?

Comment: the code is not CSS but LESS, it's not as simple as doing a copy paste... you need the compiled version or simply re-write it, it's a short one

Comment: If you turn on SCSS (Sass) in your Fiddle, your code will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To view the compiled CSS from your CodePen us the `View compiled CSS` option.
[image]

You CSS is then:

```
.loader {
  color: #0079f2;
  font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30vh;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.loader span {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 0.4s alternate infinite ease-in-out;
          animation: pulse 0.4s alternate infinite ease-in-out;
}
.loader span:nth-child(odd) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
          animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
            transform: scale(0.8);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}
@keyframes pulse {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
            transform: scale(0.8);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}
```

Which works in the fiddle.